# sd_setImage show blue image

Tags: swift, uibutton, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage to set the cells button image:

```
cell.categoryButton.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:cell.image), for: .normal, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image"))
```

but what I get is a blue image like that: I don't know why
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sd_setBackgroundImage` property since you are setting the background image of a button (`UIButton`), not setting an image to `UIImageView`.

```
cell.categoryButton.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string:cell.image), for: .normal, completed: nil)
```